# Why is there a #define ID_INLINE inline define in Doom source code?

Tags: c++, macros, inline, c-preprocessor

In Doom 3 source code, ID_INLINE macros is used instead of inline, which is declared as `#define ID_INLINE inline`. What reason there is to use this macro instead of simple inline?

Comment: Because then you can un-inline all the functions by changing a single line of code?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth your comment actually seems like a pretty good answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason many other software packages uses a "inline macro". It serves two purposes:

1. It gives the programmer one simple place to "turn off all inlining" (which is very useful sometimes when debugging things) - and you can do it "per file" by doing `#undef ID_INLINE` followed by `#define ID_INLINE` - or change the overall macro to affect the entire project.
2. Some (old) compilers don't support standard `inline` keyword, or you may need to use special magic to convince the compiler to inline functions. So using an "inline macro" allows this to be changed for the whole project (at least if the programmers follow the coding standard).

With modern compilers, the former is certainly the main point.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for it is to have a way to redefine this macro as following, probably for debugging purposes:

```
#define ID_INLINE
```